# Exception being thrown when adding an item to a ListCollectionView

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, exception

When I run the following test, I get an ArgumentOutOfRangeException:

```
[TestClass]
public class ReproduceException
{
    [TestMethod]
    public void Doesnt_throw_when_adding_to_grouped_collection()
    {
        var collection = new ListCollectionView(new List<Test>());
        collection.SortDescriptions.Add(new SortDescription("IsTrue", ListSortDirection.Ascending));
        collection.GroupDescriptions.Add(new PropertyGroupDescription("Name"));
        collection.AddNewItem(new Test() { Name = "Bob", IsTrue = false });
        collection.CommitNew();

    }
}

public class Test
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public bool IsTrue { get; set; }
}
```

An I get the following exception:

```
System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.
Parameter name: index
at System.ThrowHelper.ThrowArgumentOutOfRangeException()
at System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection`1.RemoveAt(Int32 index)
at System.Windows.Data.ListCollectionView.CommitNewForGrouping()
at System.Windows.Data.ListCollectionView.CommitNew()
```

Am I perhaps not using the `AddNewItem` / `CommitNew` in the right way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Possible solutions:

1) Do before adding a new item

```
 collection.NewItemPlaceholderPosition = NewItemPlaceholderPosition.AtBeginning;
```

2) Basically try out adding items before creation of the Grouping and Sorting:

```
var collection = new ListCollectionView(new List<Test>());            
collection.AddNewItem(new Test() { Name = "Bob", IsTrue = false });
collection.CommitNew();

collection.SortDescriptions.Add(new SortDescription("IsTrue", 
                                          ListSortDirection.Ascending));   
collection.GroupDescriptions.Add(new PropertyGroupDescription("Name"));
```

## Analysis:

After digging into the .NET Reflector, `CommitNew()` method has following check:

```
// !!! When you've added GroupDescription this.IsGrouping becomes true!
if (this.IsGrouping)
{
    this.CommitNewForGrouping();
}
```

Since you've added GroupDescription it would commit for grouping:

```
private void CommitNewForGrouping()
{
    int num;   

    // !!! I believe it is None by default
    switch (this.NewItemPlaceholderPosition)
    {
        case NewItemPlaceholderPosition.AtBeginning:
            num = 1;
            break;

        case NewItemPlaceholderPosition.AtEnd:
            num = this._group.Items.Count - 2;
            break;

        default:
            // !!! Since you've not added groups -1 would be assigned to num
            num = this._group.Items.Count - 1;
            break;
    }
    int index = this._newItemIndex;
    object item = this.EndAddNew(false);

    // This method will call RemoveAt(num) where num == -1 in your case
    this._group.RemoveSpecialItem(num, item, false);
    this.ProcessCollectionChanged(new NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs(NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Add, 
             item, index));

}

internal void RemoveSpecialItem(int index, object item, bool loading)
{
     ...
     // will fail since index always -1
     base.ProtectedItems.RemoveAt(index);
     ...
}
```

LCV has private method `ProcessCollectionChangedWithAdjustedIndex` which adjust index in different scenarios but it is not called whilst adding a new item with Grouping enables, I'm not sure why so looks like this is by design (?!) so you have manually specify placeholder `AtBeginning` for the new items.

Comment: 2) I can confirm that adding the sort and group after adding the item works, but unfortunately I need to be able to add new items after setting up the collection view and would rather not keep adding / removing the sorting and grouping :)

Comment: Solution 1) That worked! Thanks so much. Do you think this is expected behaviour or perhaps a bug?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure, but I think, that you should use `AddNew()` method rather than AddNewItem. You are going to call `CommitNew()`, whithout calling `AddNew()`, and there no begining transaction, so exception is thrown.

AddNewItem() summary: `Adds the specified object to the collection.`

AddNew() summary: `Starts an add transaction and returns the pending new item.`

CommitNew() summary: `Ends the add transaction and saves the pending new item.`

So, you should write next lines of code:

```
Test pendingItem = (Test)collection2.AddNew();
pendingItem.Name = "Bob";
pendingItem.IsTrue = false;
collection2.CommitNew();
```

Comment: I've just tried that, and unfortunately it throws the same exception